# KMeans in Python - Retaining Sample Weights After Transforming Vars

Tags: python, k-means

My dataframe (df) is comprised of a mixture of Boolean, continuous vars, and a field called wt_cnt indicating the weight of the record.

The MinMaxScaler is applied to my data before I do the clustering:

```
mms = MinMaxScaler()
mms.fit(data)
data_transformed = mms.transform(data)
```

And the KMeans routine is as follows:

```
sum_of_squared_distances = []
K = range(1,15)
for k in K:
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=k) #init model
    km = km.fit(data_transformed, sample_weight=None) #fit model
    sum_of_squared_distances.append(km.inertia_) #overall SSE
```

But I would like to RETAIN my initial field from my first df (wt_cnt) that designates the weighting of my cluster analysis. This has been difficult for me to do because data_transformed is just a matrix and not a df. Any suggestions on how to most effectively and efficiently do this?

Example below:

```
data = [[2,12669,5]
      ,[2,7057,1]
      ,[2,6353,1]
      ,[1,13265,3]
      ,[2,22615,1]      
      ,[2,9413,1]      
      ,[2,12126,2]      
      ,[2,7579,1]      
      ,[1,5963,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Nm','Frsh','wt_cnt'])
mms = MinMaxScaler()
mms.fit(df)
data_transformed = mms.transform(df)
sum_of_squared_distances = []
K = range(1,5)
for k in K:
    km = KMeans(n_clusters=k)
    km = km.fit(data_transformed, sample_weight=None)
    sum_of_squared_distances.append(km.inertia_)
plt.plot(K, sum_of_squared_distances, 'bx-')
plt.xlabel('k')
plt.ylabel('SS dists')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please show a sample of the dataframe at each iteration and the weight matrix?

Comment: The example above shows it and the weights in the  last column. The first problem is that the transformation includes the weights - they should be excluded. Then when the Kmeans procedure runs it should use sample_weight=wt_cnt without any transformation.